# ¿Está bien hacer casting entre una union C++ y cualquier tipo de sus miembros?

Tags: c++

Hola estoy usando uniones en mi código pero me parece molesto tener que revisar el nombre que le puse a sus miembros, entonces se me ocurrió usar casting en su lugar y quedó así de cómodo:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    
    union M{
        double membernamea;
        int    membernameb;
        bool   membernamec;
    };

    M m;
    
    //acceder al miembro double
    (double&)m=34.54;

    //leer el miembro double 
    std::cout << ((double&)m);

    return 0;
}
```

Está bien definido usar el casting estilo C para acceder a miembros de union o es un comportamiento indefinido y es una ilusión porque parece funcionar.

Comment: Si usas un IDE, es más cómodo acceder por el nombre de las variables que haciendo una conversión.

Answer (score 1):

> Está bien definido usar el casting estilo C para acceder a miembros de union o es un comportamiento indefinido y es una ilusión porque parece funcionar.

Respuesta genérica: **Comportamiento indefinido**.

Respuesta en el caso expuesto: **Correcto, no incurres en ningún comportamiento indefinido**.

#### ¿¿ ??

La clave aquí es el concepto de `Standard Memory Layout`. A grandes rasgos, una `struct` o `class` o `union` se considera `Standard Memory Layout` si `virtual` no aparece por ninguna parte en su definición ni en su cadena de herencia.

Si una clase tiene alguna función-miembro `virtual` (incluido el destructor), o hay herencia `virtual` en su cadena de herencias, o alguna de sus clases base tiene alguna función-miembro `virtual`, dicha clase **NO** cumple con `Standard Memory Layout`.

El tema aquí es que la implementación de la *virtualidad* es **dependiente-del-compilador**. Lo cual impide garantizar que un puntero a instancia es equivalente a un puntero al primer miembro de la clase.

Por lo tanto, en una `union`, siempre que todas de sus variables-miembro cumplan con `Standard Memory Layout`, se cumple que un puntero a la instancia es intercambiable con un puntero a cualquiera de sus miembros.

Así pues, esto es **correcto**:

```
int main() {
    
    union M{
        double membernamea;
        int    membernameb;
        bool   membernamec;
    };

    M m;
    
    //acceder al miembro double
    (double&)m=34.54;
```

Sin embargo, esto es **erróneo** e incurrimos en comportamiento indefinido:

```
int main() {
    struct Algo {
        virtual ~Algo( );
    };
    
    union M{
        Algo   membernamea;
        int    membernameb;
        bool   membernamec;
    };

    M m;
    
    //acceder al miembro int
    (int&)m=34.54;
```

Observa que estas reglas se aplican a todo tipo de clases, no solo a las `union`. Por ejemplo, esto es **correcto**:

```
struct A {
  int a;
};

A a;
(int *)(&a) = 10;
```

Y esto, por lo que ya vimos, es **incorrecto**:

```
struct Algo {
    virtual ~Algo( );
    int a;
};

struct A {
    Algo a;
};

A a;

(int *)(&a) = 10;
```

Answer (score 1):

Respuesta corta: En general no.

---

Respuesta larga: Las `union` en C++ son un constructo peligroso. Según el estándar del lenguaje ([borrador del estándar C++ septiembre de 2022](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/n4917.pdf)) sólo uno de los miembros de la `union` está activo en cada momento (traducción y resaltado míos):

> #### 11.5 Uniones
>
> ##### 11.5.1 General
>
> 1. Una `union` es una clase definida con la palabra clave `union`.
> 2. **En una `union`, un miembro no estático está activo si su nombre se refiere a un objeto cuyo ciclo de vida haya empezado y no haya finalizado**. **Como mucho uno de los miembros no estáticos de una `unión` puede estar activo en cualquier momento**, es decir, el valor de como máximo uno de los miembros no estáticos puede ser almacenado en una `union` en cualquier momento.

En el mismo apartado, un poco más adelante el estándar nos da más información con un ejemplo:

> [*Ejemplo 2*:
>
> ```
> union A { int x; int y[4]; };
> struct B { A a; };
> union C { B b; int k; };
> int f() {
>     C c; // no empieza el ciclo de vida de ningún miembro de la union
>     c.b.a.y[3] = 4; // OK, S(c.b.a.y[3]) contiene c.b y c.b.a.y;
>                     // crea objectos para almacenar los miembros c.b y c.b.a.y de la union
>
>     return c.b.a.y[3]; // OK, c.b.a.y se refiere a un objeto nuevo
> }
> struct X { const int a; int b; };
> union Y { X x; int k; };
> void g() {
> Y y = { { 1, 2 } }; // OK, y.x es el miembro activo de la union
> int n = y.x.a;
> y.k = 4; // OK, finaliza la vida de of y.x, y.k es el miembro activo de la union
> y.x.b = n; // comportamiento indefinido: y.x.b se modifica fuera de su ciclo de vida,
>            // S(y.x.b) está vacío porque el constructor de X está borrado,
>            // así que el ciclo de vida de y.x no empieza
> }
> ```
>
> *— fin del ejemplo*]

Por lo tanto, si que puedes acabar en un comportamiento indefinido si no vas con cuidado. Si quieres una utilidad parecida a una `union` pero que te permita leer datos por tipo usa [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <variant>

int main() {
    
    using M = std::variant<double, int, bool>;

    M m;
    
    //acceder al miembro double
    m=34.54;

    //leer el miembro double 
    std::cout << std::get<double>(m);

    return 0;
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY1NCsIwEEbXnVMMuKlUrWjd2J8beIhpOpZAfiRN3IhXN0arCM5yeO974nJZC0VmjHEhjVBhYGyknbxj0h38fldykozvAKTxqEmafIk3wHSQhUmaEU/Y4uSH4/HDNoMNveIVJmOFvbWqqwGyE@r645UlCcEDOySFWrLuncXZgky3@2pzqF5KWSpOEP9DaeIdFDZ4bJq5PvK33OV6@dId@@AMbmu4x/gQZ0XjFNcJbkVR7OgJ)</kbd>.